Al hacer clic en autocomplete de un textbox me rellene los otros textbox
tengo un formulario el cual en un textbox escribo la información deseada para consultar y el autocomplete me funciona, pero deseo que al hacer clic en la ventana de sugerencias del autocompletar me rellene los demás textbox con información de la Base de Datos.

En el evento load del formulario tengo este código:
txtDescripcion.AutoCompleteCustomSource = LoadAutoComplete();
txtDescripcion.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
txtDescripcion.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

Tengo este método para invocar la lista y asignarla al autocomplete.
private AutoCompleteStringCollection LoadAutoComplete()
    {
        Servicios servicios = new Servicios();

        DataTable dt = servicios.ConsultaServicios(this);

        AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            stringCol.Add(Convert.ToString(row["descripcion"]));
        }

        return stringCol;
    }

Cabe destacar que todos los controles que hasta ahora estoy usando son de Windows Form.  De esta manera me funciona el autocomplete, entonces lo que necesito es que cuando empiece a escribir y me muestre las sugerencias que al hacer clic en una de las sugerencias me dispare un evento y ejecutar una búsqueda en la DB y llenar los demás textbox del formulario.

ok y cual seria el problema con eso??? y que tecnologia de vista estas usando??

Sólo logro que funcione el autocomplete del primer textbox, los demás no se completan al hacer clic en la sugerencia mostrada y estoy usando c# @gbianchi

c# es el lenguaje de base.. pero las pantallas se pueden hacer con asp, winforms, wpf, maui... sin saber eso, dificl ayudarte..

@gbianchi perdón por no ser específico, estoy trabajando con winforms.

y ninguno de los eventos de ese cuadro de texto te sirvio????

@gbianchi Lo he intentado, pero no me dispara el evento.

Que evento? como es tu codigo? cual es el tipo de textbox que usas? como haces el autocomplete? falta muchisima informacion como para que alguien pueda darte una mano...

@gbianchi Acabo de editar la pregunta para hacerla mas descriptiva, creo que ahí puedes apreciar mejor mi duda.

cualquier evento del textbox te sirve.. change.. lostfocus... sigo sin entender cual seria el problema.. no hay un evento especifico que se ejecute al terminar el autocomplete...

yo creo que lo que quiere es que al seleccionar una opción del AutoComplete, se carguen los datos en los otros TextBox. Para eso, puedes hacer varias cosas, una de ellas sería ejecutar una consulta que se encargue de traer los datos que necesitas con el texto que seleccionaste y luego lo distribuyes a cada textbox
